# Returning possible null even when validate it

Tags: typescript

I have the following code:

```
export function validaterUserContributors(
  propList: FormPropList<IdentityUserDto>
) {
  const firstNameNode = propList.dropByValue(
    'AbpIdentity::DisplayName:Name',
    (prop, displayName) => prop.displayName === displayName
  );

  const emailControlValue = firstNameNode?.value;

  if (emailControlValue) {
    const emailControl = new FormControl(
      emailControlValue,
      Validators.required
    );

    propList.add(emailControl.value);

}
```

As you can see, I created a new form control of the first one I dropped, and I added a validator., so I want to add it in the last line `propList.add(emailControl.value);`

But this is throwing me the following error:

> Argument of type 'FormProp | null' is not assignable
> to parameter of type 'FormProp'.   Type 'null' is not
> assignable to type 'FormProp'

I don't know why it has possible null if I use an if statement to control that `if (emailControlValue) {}`

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that others can copy and paste into their own IDEs to see what you're seeing.  The only errors present when we do that should be the ones you're asking about.  So any private or third-party things should be defined for us, or even better, replaced with analogs native to TypeScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be with the way you're using the optional chaining operator `(?)` when accessing the `value` property of `firstNameNode`

Even though you're checking if `emailControlValue` is truthy before creating a new `FormControl`, TypeScript is still recognizing that `firstNameNode` could potentially be `null` or `undefined` due to the usage of `?`

To fix this issue, you can either remove the `?` and use a non-null assertion operator `(!)` like this:

```
const emailControlValue = firstNameNode!.value;
```

Or, you can use a nullish coalescing operator `(??)` to provide a default value in case firstNameNode is null or undefined:

```
const emailControlValue = firstNameNode?.value ?? '';
```